# Method annotated with @Schedule is not scheduled

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb-3.1

I am trying to create a simple timer job with ejb3.1 to do some cleaning up. My bean looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ExpirationSchedulerBean {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExpirationSchedulerBean.class);

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void cleanup() {
        logger.warn("Schedule Timer fired - " + new Date());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        logger.warn("I AM IN STARTUP()");
    }
}
```

My log files show that there is nothing wrong with the logger, as *"I AM IN STARTUP()"* is printed fine. However, the scheduled method is never run.

I tried creating a `Timer` instead, using:

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

@PostConstruct
public void startup() {
    logger.warn("I AM IN STARTUP()");
    timerService.createIntervalTimer(0, 5000, new TimerConfig());
}

@Timeout
public void sayHello() {
    logger.warn("Timeout from timer "+new Date());
}
```

But the server seems to dislike that too, I get *JBAS014239: The timer service has been disabled. Please add a  entry into the ejb section of the server configuration to enable it.* How do I get the method marked `@Schedule` to run every five seconds?

EDIT: I use JBoss 6.4

Comment: I think it  is not enabled in your profile. At least for v7, it worked for me when downloading the "everything" distribution and start the server using:
`./standalone.sh -server-config=standalone-preview.xml`

Comment: @spa Hmm, that seems to be true! However, I guess I should be able to just enable it in my standalone.xml then?

Comment: Yeah of course - it just enables everything. That's not what you want most of the time. But you can search that config for the timer stuff.

Comment: I just found that the timer-service configuration in my standalone.xml was commented out. I think that `@Schedule` uses timer services in the background and thus failed, why it didn't give me an error message is beyond my knowledge though. I will enable timer-services and see if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, just as @spa mentioned, is that my configuration lacked necessary dependencies. The `@Schedule`-annotation uses timer-service, so I needed to add the following to my standalone.xml:

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
    <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
</timer-service>
```

Without the dependency it failed silently making the problem hard to find.